# Not able to switch LTR to RTL in TabBar in Xamarin Forms iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I'm working on localization for an app, on switching the language the tabbar should invert, i have a renderer through which i'm trying to do this

```
  if (e.NewElement != null)
            {
                _tabbedController = (UITabBarController)ViewController;
                ViewController.View.SemanticContentAttribute = UISemanticContentAttribute.ForceLeftToRight;
            }
```

I'm doing this in the onElementChanged Method, but for some reason this does not seem to affect, am i doing somthing wrong in this or is there any other way to do this ?
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: To implement RTL in Xamarin.Forms , we also need to set the `FlowDirection` 
of ContentPage .Check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/localization/right-to-left#respecting-device-flow-direction.

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT i've tried that, it doesnt seem to work for Tabbar for some reason in iOS, but still i believe the renderer method should work right ?

Comment: Try to invoke the code in method `ViewWillAppear` .